# Find $\frac{3\sqrt{4a^{3}}}{5\sqrt{3a^{4}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{3\sqrt{4a^{3}}}{5\sqrt{3a^{4}}}$$

I got this question on my math homework, but I'm not sure if the answer I got is the correct one.
I'll link a picture of the work I did on it, along with the answer I got below.

[image: The answer I got]

Answer (score 1):

Note that $a>0$,

\begin{align*}
  \frac{3\sqrt{4a^3}}{5\sqrt{3a^4}} &=
  \frac{3\times 2a\sqrt{a}}{5\times a^2\sqrt{3}} \\
  &= \frac{2\sqrt{3} \times \sqrt{a}}{5a} \\
  &= \frac{2\sqrt{3a}}{5a}
\end{align*}

If no needs to rationalize the denominator, I prefer writing as $\fbox{$\dfrac{2\sqrt{3}}{5\sqrt{a}}$}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{3\sqrt{4a^3}}{5\sqrt{3a^4}}=\frac{3\sqrt{4}\sqrt{a^2}\sqrt{a}}{5\sqrt{3}\sqrt{(a^2)^2}}=
\frac{3\cdot2\cdot a\cdot\sqrt{a}}{5\sqrt{3}\cdot a^2}
=\frac{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}\cdot2\cdot a\cdot\sqrt{a}}{5\sqrt{3}\cdot a\cdot\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{a}}
=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{5\sqrt{a}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

After your first step, you should have $\sqrt{a^8} = a^4$ on the bottom instead of $a^8$.  You should end up with the answer
$$
\frac{2\sqrt {3a} }{5 a}
$$